# Visual Studio Code extension: child_process.fork doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm working on an extension for Visual Studio Code and I need to fork a child process. The process never appears to exit, send messages, or even be running (I've tried writing a file from the child process to verify that it's running).

Here's my code for forking the child process:

```
let process = require('child_process').fork('./child', [], {});
process.on('message', message => console.log('message: ' + message)); // handler is never called
process.on('exit', code => console.log('exited with code ' + code)); // handler is never called
```

Here's child.js:

```
require('fs').writeFileSync(__dirname + '/hello.txt', 'Hello', 'utf8'); // file never gets written
process.send('hello');
```

It should be noted that trying to run the same script with `spawn('node', [__dirname + '/child.js'], {})` works as expected.

Just testing this out in the debug instance.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think `./child` gets resolved to `path.join(process.cwd, './child')` and `process.cwd` is not equal to `__dirname`.